# "No-Const Pointer to Const " call function

Tags: c++, c, pointers, exception

I have to throw a pointer like this. And i want to call function of Derived in main class.

```
using namespace std;
class Base
    {
    public: 
        virtual ~Base() {};
        virtual const char * what() { return "Base"; };
        int value = 0;
    };

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    ~Derived() {};
    const char * what() { return "Derived"; };
    int value = 1;
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        throw new Derived();
    }
    catch (Base const * b)
    {
        //HOW TO CALL b->what();
        delete b;
    }
}
```

When i try to call what() function, i got error **the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function "Base::what"**
Can you show me a solution?.
Thanks.

Comment: The `what` method is not a `const` method.

Comment: You can't call `what()` because it can only be called for a mutable object, and your pointer is a `const` pointer. Either change `what()`, in both base or derived, to be a `const` class method, or catch a non-const pointer.

Comment: Because this class will be extend std::exception so...
Anyway, If i catch (Base *b), can i still delete b without memory leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Base const* b` means `b` is a pointer that point to immutable object( const object). In c++, an immutable object can just use const methods, an example for const method is:

```
class Base
{
public:
   int method1(/*some parameters*/) const  //this is a const method
   {
      //do something
   } 
   const int method2(/*some parameters*/)  //this is NOT a const method
   {
     //do something
   }
}
```

So, you must chang `b` to a normal pointer, not a pointer to const object. Or make `what()` as a const method.

Comment: Because this class will be extend std::exception so what is a method override... Anyway, If i catch (Base *b), can i still delete b without memory leak?

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand your mean?

Comment: I wana throw a pointer exception, call a method of it, and delete it outside when i catch it.
If i catch (Base const * b) i can delete without memory leak, but can't call method, if i catch (Base * b) i can call, but can't delete it , memory leak will be happen. "what()" method is a method of std::exception, i just override it.